# Redirecting zip files on Github pages

Tags: apache, .htaccess, github-pages, http-redirect

I have some pages running in an Apache server and I have the following redirect:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteRule ^file\.zip$ https://github.com/user/repo/releases/download/v0.1/file.zip [R=302]
</IfModule>
```

It works very well. The idea is haven't the zip files in my server, just do a redirect. And I can use a short url, like mydomain.com/file.zip. How I said before, it works very well.

The problem is:
I'm moving those pages to Github Pages and I don't know if is possible to do a redirect like this, specifically to zip files. I know that is possible with files that return text, like .html, .md etc, but I don't know how to do with zip files.

ps: actually I'm putting the zip file inside the Github pages folder of my repo, but I don't want to do this. I want to just redirect it.

Thanks.

Comment: Hey there, it has been a while, but how did it go?